# Not inserting null values

Tags: php, html, yii2, isset

I am trying to insert multiple values in the todo input of the form. but if i do not input a value to any input the null value is inserted in the database. This is my controller action:

```
public function actionAdd()
{       
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        $add = new Project();
        $add->project_name = $request->post('project');
        $add->deadline = $request->post('deadline');
        $add->profile_id = $request->post('profile_id');
        $add->project_status = "Running";
        $add->save();
        $getlast = Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertId();
        $todo = $request->post('todo');

        if (isset($todo)) {
            foreach ($todo as $to) {
                $add = new Todo();
                $add->todo_name=$to;
                $add->status="Running";
                $add->project_id=$getlast;
                $add->save();
            }
        }
        echo json_encode(TRUE); die;
    }
    echo json_encode(FALSE);die;
}
```

the form is:

```
<form class="formclass" method="POST" action="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;?>/todo/add/" role="form"  id="register-form" novalidate="novalidate">

                  <label>    Project Name: </label>       <input type="name" name="project" class="form-control"  placeholder="Project Name" required><br><br>
                  <input type="hidden" name="profile_id" value="<?php echo $profile_id;?>">
                  <label>    Todo: </label><br>
                  <textarea type="text" name="todo[]" placeholder="Todo Description..."></textarea>
                  <div id="dynamicInput">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');"></span>
                    </div><br>
                  <label> Project Deadline:</label><br>
                  <input type="date" name="deadline"><br><br>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add Project</button><BR><BR>                      
        </form>
```

And the jquery is:

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 10;
function addInput(divName)
{ 
  if (counter != limit) 
   {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "<br><textarea type='text' name='todo[]' placeholder='Todo Description...'></textarea>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);    
          counter++;     
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: @RafaelShkembi if i donot input any value, null is inserted.

Comment: that's how it works. If you dont post any data default is null. Post olso your php form to take a look at

Comment: @RafaelShkembi ok. updated the question.

Comment: there is an extension for dynamic forms in yii2

Comment: please show you todo models validation rules .

Answer (score 0):

Could be you problem is related to the validation rules  ..

for check this and only for debugging  try use  $add->savel(false)

```
         $add = new Todo();
            $add->todo_name=$to;
            $add->status="Running";
            $add->project_id=$getlast;
            $add->save(false);
```

if in this case the rows are inserted the check for validations rule (eventually comment temporary) .. for find the wrong rules or condition